# A PHP error was encountered severity:trying to get non-object file name:

Tags: codeigniter

view part where the error occured

```
<select name="standard" class="form-control">
    <option <?php if($course->medium =='E'){ echo "selected";} ?>  value="English" >English</option>
    <option  <?php  if($course->medium =='M'){ echo "selected";} ?>  value="Malayalam">Malayalam</option>
</select>
```

model part

```
public static function getStandard($id){

    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from('standard');
    $this->db->where('id',$id);

     $res=$this->db->get();

    foreach($res->result() as  $value) {

        return $value;
    }

}
```

controller part

```
public function add_standard($action='',$id='') {

      $this->load_syles();

         $course = array();
     if ($action == 'edit' and $id != '' and is_numeric($id)) {
    $course = $this->news_model->getStandard($id);
     }

    $this->data['course'] = $course ;

    $this->data['title'] = 'Add Standard';
    $this->data['page_header'] = "Add Standard";
    $this->data['page_header_desc'] = "Add Standard";
    $details=$this->news_model->viewAllStandard();
    $this->data['details']=$details;
    $this->data['count']=count($details);
    $this->data['is_edit']=$action;
```

Comment: your fetching object as array .you should use like this <?php if($course['medium'] =='E'){ echo "selected";} ?>  instead of <?php if($course->medium =='E'){ echo "selected";} ?>

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

```
$course = array()
```

and then used

```
$course->medium
```

as if it was an object

you should use `$course['medium']` in the view(html)

Answer (score 0):

Change your model like

```
public static function getStandard($id)
{
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from('standard');
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $res=$this->db->get();
    return $res->row_array();
}
```

Change `$course->medium` to `$course['medium']`

```
<select name="standard" class="form-control">
<option <?php if($course['medium'] =='E'){ echo "selected";} ?>  value="English" >English</option>
<option  <?php  if($course$course['medium'] =='M'){ echo "selected";} ?>  value="Malayalam">Malayalam</option>
```